# using static method

Tags: java

I'm unsure how to use the static method in this program. I am coding a program that will calculate a factorial of a number between 0 and 10. The user can enter the number and the program should calculate the factorial.
I had originally written a functional program with all of the code coming from the main and then when I double checked the assignment rubric I noticed I was supposed to place the calculation for getting the factorial in a static method. I believe my issue is towards the bottom where I'm asking the user to enter the number I don't send it to the calculator. I guess I'm unclear on how that is done. I'm new so I apologize for my poor coding and I appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import scanner class
public class FactorialCalculator {

    public static long calculator(long fact, int num) {
        for(int i = 1; i<=num; i++) {
            fact *= i;
        }
        return fact;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner calc = new Scanner(System.in); //create new scanner calc
        int num = 0;
        long fact = 1;
        //welcome user to the Factorial Calculator
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Factorial Calculator.");
        System.out.println();
        String choice = "y";
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer that's greater than 0 and less than 10: ");
            num = calc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("The Factorial for " + num + " is " + fact +".");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Would you like to continue? y/n");
            choice = calc.next();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note - the method that calculates the factorial should only need one input parameter - get rid of the first parameter and initialize it in the method.

Comment: @MichaelBurr That should be done, as right now `fact` is not reset between loops. Keep in mind that fact has to be declared in the calculator method `long fact=1;` as well as in `main()`.

Comment: a `static` method can invoke only another static methods from the same class. Your `main` method is static, so if you want to call `calculator` it must be static too. You can refer to the static keyword [here](http://tinyurl.com/76lr6un) or to [this](http://tinyurl.com/8yjq7fg) post.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thank you for the links. I have to revisit them but what I read was a little more helpful than what I was reading from.

Comment: @JeremyBorton sure just google `java static keyword` and there will be tons of info for you. Maybe you want to learn more of [Java keywords](http://tinyurl.com/7s7btzx) and their use :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never calling `calculator(long fact, int num);`

just call it with

```
    fact = calculator(fact,num);
```

right after:

```
    num = calc.nextInt();
```

**EDIT:**

I would recommend you also remove the `long fact` as an argument to `calculator()` and add it into the method body of `calculator()`

Ex:

```
public static long calculator(int num){
   long fact=1;
   for(int i = 1; i<=num; i++){
      fact *= i;
   }
   return fact;
}
```

Comment: I'm noticing now my calculations are off when they weren't before. in my main method I did delcare int num = 0; and long fact = 1; if I don't have that then I get errors is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Place this just before you print the result:

```
fact = FactorialCalculator.calculator(fact, num)
```

Answer (score 0):

As your `calculator` method is a static method so you can call it directly by using the class name.

```
num = calc.nextInt();
long result_factorial = FactorialCalculator.calcuator(fact,num)
```

Your method should be

```
public static long (int num)
        {
              long fact = 1;
                for(int i = 1; i<=num; i++)
                {
                fact *= i;
                }
            return fact;
        }
```

Remove the `fact` initialisation from your main method.

Comment: You shouldn't create an object, it's a static method.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet: I was trying to explain the difference between `static` and `instance` method but than i dropped that idea but forgot to remove my sentence.

Comment: @RanRag it's in the same class, you can simply call it as `calculator();` not `FactorialCalculator.calcuator();`

Comment: @Hawken: I know that but was trying to do it the general way.What if not in same class.?

Comment: @Hawken: That is how i called it. `FactorialCalculator.calcuator(fact,num)`

Comment: As I told you what if they were not in the same class.So, I was trying to be as general as possible.I think there are no performance issue in calling `FactorialCalculator.calcuator(fact,num)` or `calcuator(fact,num)` if in same class.

Comment: @Hawken: Above comment **was trying to be as general as possible**. Do you believe there will be any performance issues.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7826/discussion-between-hawken-and-ranrag)

Comment: @Hawken: Sorry,I believe there is no point in discussing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a static method of a class as:

variableType variableName = ClassName.MethodName(parameters);

In your case you can simply call:

```
        fact = FactorialCalculator.calculator(fact, num);
```

It should be inserted somewhere AFTER when you ASK the user for the input num, and BEFORE you print out the fact number to the user

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner; //import scanner class
public class FactorialCalculator 
{

    public static long calculator(int num)
    {
            long fact = 1;

            for(int i = 1; i<=num; i++)
            {
                fact *= i;
            }
        return fact;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner calc = new Scanner(System.in); //create new scanner calc
        int num;
        //welcome user to the Factorial Calculator
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Factorial Calculator.");
        System.out.println();
        String choice = "y";
        while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
            {
            System.out.println("Please enter an integer that's greater than 0 and less than 10: ");
            num = calc.nextInt();

            fact = FactorialCalculator.calculator(num);

            System.out.println("The Factorial for " + num + " is " + fact +".");

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Would you like to continue? y/n");
            choice = calc.next();
            System.out.println();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to offer an explanation for what you are changing.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

```
fact = FactorialCalculator.calculator(fact, num)
```

And you should notice that the program will calculate factorial right for the first time, then it starts to fail since the second time. Fixing that bug is your job.